# Ubuntu 22.04 on iMac27 late 2013 no sound on headphones

Tags: sound, 22.04

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my iMac 27 late 2013 as a main and single os.
There is sound on speakers but no sound when I plugged in headphones.
When I plugged in headphones I see that the Output device switched to headphones, I see indicators working but no sound.
When I unplugged headphones the sound is working from speakers.

When I have Ubuntu 20.04 on external drive there was a same problem and I solve it by editing /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and adding options snd-hda-intel model=imac27
and executing command from step1 - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure
and it works.

But now nothing.
Please help me if you know how!